# Training Accuracy Stuck at 0.50+-

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have been working on a comparison of the CNN and RNN deep learning models for sentimental analysis.

I built the CNN following this guide:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-word-embedding-model-predicting-movie-review-sentiment/ , and I got an accuracy of 90+ in CNN.

However, when I tried to recreate a LSTM model, the accuracy seems to hover around 0.5+-, and doesnt seems to improve over time. I wonder what is wrong with my codes I the only thing I have done is to replace the existing CNN model with LSTM in the **model.add** section. I have tried to change the loss from "binary" to "categorical", and different activation function. It still doesn't resolve the issue.

[CNN RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJhV8.png)
[LSTM RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAmqS.png)

This is my CNN model which worked fine

```
 # load the vocabulary

    vocab_filename = 'vocab.txt'
    vocab = load_doc(vocab_filename)
    vocab = vocab.split()
    vocab = set(vocab)

    # load all training reviews

    positive_docs = process_docs('C:/Users/zenhu/OneDrive/Desktop/Final Year Project/archive/review_polarity/txt_sentoken/pos', vocab, True)
    negative_docs = process_docs('C:/Users/zenhu/OneDrive/Desktop/Final Year Project/archive/review_polarity/txt_sentoken/neg', vocab, True)
    train_docs = negative_docs + positive_docs

    # create the tokenizer

    tokenizer = Tokenizer()

    # fit the tokenizer on the documents

    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_docs)

    # sequence encode

    encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_docs)

    # pad sequences

    max_length = max([len(s.split()) for s in train_docs])
    Xtrain = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

    # define training labels, TRAINING DATASET

    ytrain = array([0 for _ in range(900)] + [1 for _ in range(900)])

    # load all test reviews

    positive_docs = process_docs('C:/Users/zenhu/OneDrive/Desktop/Final Year Project/archive/review_polarity/txt_sentoken/pos', vocab, False)
    negative_docs = process_docs('C:/Users/zenhu/OneDrive/Desktop/Final Year Project/archive/review_polarity/txt_sentoken/neg', vocab, False)
    test_docs = negative_docs + positive_docs

    # sequence encode

    encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_docs)

    # pad sequences

    Xtest = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

    # define test labels, TESTING DATASET

    ytest = array([0 for _ in range(100)] + [1 for _ in range(100)])

    # define vocabulary size (largest integer value)

    vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
    print(vocab_size)

    # define model

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, input_length=max_length))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    print(model.summary())

    # compile network

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # fit network

    history=model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, verbose=2)

    # evaluate

    loss, acc = model.evaluate(Xtest, ytest, verbose=0)
    print('Test Accuracy: %f' % (acc*100))
    print(history.history.keys())

#summarize history for accuracy

    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()

# summarize history for loss

    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```

This is my current LSTM model

```
    # load the vocabulary

    vocab_filename = 'vocab.txt'
    vocab = load_doc(vocab_filename)
    vocab = vocab.split()
    vocab = set(vocab)

    # load all training reviews

    positive_docs = process_docs('C:/Users/zenhu/OneDrive/Desktop/Final Year Project/archive/review_polarity/txt_sentoken/pos', vocab, True)
    negative_docs = process_docs('C:/Users/zenhu/OneDrive/Desktop/Final Year Project/archive/review_polarity/txt_sentoken/neg', vocab, True)
    train_docs = negative_docs + positive_docs

    # create the tokenizer

    tokenizer = Tokenizer()

    # fit the tokenizer on the documents

    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_docs)

    # sequence encode

    encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_docs)

    # pad sequences

    max_length = max([len(s.split()) for s in train_docs])
    Xtrain = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

    # define training labels, TRAINING DATASET

    ytrain = array([0 for _ in range(900)] + [1 for _ in range(900)])

    # load all test reviews

    positive_docs = process_docs('C:/Users/zenhu/OneDrive/Desktop/Final Year Project/archive/review_polarity/txt_sentoken/pos', vocab, False)
    negative_docs = process_docs('C:/Users/zenhu/OneDrive/Desktop/Final Year Project/archive/review_polarity/txt_sentoken/neg', vocab, False)
    test_docs = negative_docs + positive_docs

    # sequence encode

    encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_docs)

    # pad sequences

    Xtest = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

    # define test labels, TESTING DATASET

    ytest = array([0 for _ in range(100)] + [1 for _ in range(100)])

    # define vocabulary size (largest integer value)

    vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

    # define model

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, input_length=max_length))
    model.add(LSTM(units=100))
    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    print(model.summary())

    # compile network

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # fit network

    history=model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, verbose=2)

    # evaluate

    loss, acc = model.evaluate(Xtest, ytest, verbose=0)
    print('Test Accuracy: %f' % (acc*100))
    
    print(history.history.keys())`

#summarize history for accuracy

    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()

# summarize history for loss

    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you add the last few lines of `history` output?

Comment: Let's say there is no typo/error in your RNN-based solution, which I haven't checked. In this case, issue comes from the model. 1 layer of 10 units is a really small network, even your CNN has more parameters. Try 1 or 2 layers of at least 32 units, and if it's still not working, you might have an issue in your code.

Comment: @AdarshWase alright, done updated the codes

Comment: @NiziL I tried increasing the ouput dimension of the LSTM, and its doesnt really affect the accuracy much, not a slight difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your LSTM layer. It is not returning a sequence of the same length. You must set `return_sequences=True` when stacking layer so that the second layer has a three-dimensional sequence input. After adding `return_sequences = True` parameter in your LSTM layer, it will give you around 90% accuracy for sure.

```
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences = True))
```

Comment: Oh wow, the LSTM models start to learn properly and the accuracy has drastically climbed up to 80 in no time. Thank you @Adarsh for your help. I really appreciated it very much :D